# Qt: move to thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Say if I have:

```
Class A{
Q_Object

public:
A::A(){};
void A::init(){obj = new myQobject();}
myQobject* obj;
}
```

then if the Class A is used like:

```
QThread *workerthread = new QThread;
A *worker = new A();
worker->moveToThread(workerthread);
workerthread->start();
worker->init();
```

then *myQobject obj* will live in which thread? The main thread or the worker thread?

Comment: What do you mean by 'live'?

Comment: say if I connect a signal to myQobject obj's slot through auto connection. When I triggered that signal, the slot will be executed in which thread?

Comment: @sje397 He means [thread affinity](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#thread-affinity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will live in the main thread, since you're calling `worker->init()` from the main thread. You can either use signals and slots to call `init` from the worker thread, or use [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) with a queued connection *(You don't have to specify this, as it will use `Qt::AutoConnection` by default and that will use `Qt::QueuedConnection` if `invokeMethod` is called from a different thread than the receiving object)*.

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(worker, "init",
                       Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

You can also create `myObject` in the constructor and set `this` as the parent. Then when you call [`moveToThread`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#moveToThread), the object will also move its children to the same thread.

`QObject::moveToThread`: [*Changes the thread affinity for this object and its children.*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#moveToThread)